# Is it possible to stop Spotify or any other music application playback?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create my own sleeptimer and i've found some solutions here on stackoverflow but they are all working in java and not kotlin.

so far i've tried

```
val intent = Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY")
                intent.putExtra("paused", false)
                intent.setPackage("com.spotify.music")
                sendBroadcast(intent)
```

and

```
val pauseSpotify = Intent("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.widget.PLAY")
            pauseSpotify.setPackage("com.spotify.music")
            sendBroadcast(pauseSpotify)
```

Comment: if it works for java, chances are it'll work for kotlin. as your question stands, it's too broad. post what you're struggling with _specifically_

Comment: in kotlin you have not set `paused` to false